Error of gateway urls while uploading encrypted secrets to DON - Chainlink Functions
Body
I'm trying to upload encrypted secrets to Chainlink Decentralized Oracle Network (DON) gateways using the @chainlink/functions-toolkit in my RWA project. However, I'm encountering an error when sending the request to the gateways.
Error I am getting in terminal
Error encountered when attempting to send request to DON gateway URL #1 of 2
https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/: AggregateError
Error encountered when attempting to send request to DON gateway URL #2 of 2
https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/: AggregateError
Error: Failed to send request to any of the DON gateway URLs:
["https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/","https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/"]


Script to upload secrets - uploadSecrets.js
const {
    SecretsManager,
} = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit")

const {ethers} = require('ethers');


const uploadSecrets = async () => {
    
   const routerAddress = "0xb83E47C2bC239B3bf370bc41e1459A34b41238D0"  //sepolia
    const donId = "fun-ethereum-sepolia-1"
    const gatewayUrls = [
        "https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
        "https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
    ]

    
    const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\r/g, "").trim(); 
    if (!privateKey)
        throw new Error(
            "private key not provided - check your environment variables"
        )

    const rpcUrl = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL

    if (!rpcUrl)
        throw new Error(`rpcUrl not provided  - check your environment variables`)

    const secrets = { alpacaKey: process.env.ALPACA_KEY ?? "", alpacaSecret: process.env.ALPACA_SECRET ?? "" }
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl)
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey)
    const signer = wallet.connect(provider) 

    
    const secretsManager = new SecretsManager({
        signer: signer,
        functionsRouterAddress: routerAddress,
        donId: donId,
    })
    await secretsManager.initialize()

    
    const encryptedSecretsObj = await secretsManager.encryptSecrets(secrets)
    const slotIdNumber = 0 
    const expirationTimeMinutes = 1440 


    console.log(
        `Upload encrypted secret to gateways ${gatewayUrls}. slotId ${slotIdNumber}. Expiration in minutes: ${expirationTimeMinutes}`
    )
    // Upload secrets
    const uploadResult = await secretsManager.uploadEncryptedSecretsToDON({
        encryptedSecretsHexstring: encryptedSecretsObj.encryptedSecrets,
        gatewayUrls: gatewayUrls,
        slotId: slotIdNumber,
        minutesUntilExpiration: expirationTimeMinutes,
    })

    if (!uploadResult.success)
        throw new Error(`Encrypted secrets not uploaded to ${gatewayUrls}`)

    console.log(
        `\n Secrets uploaded properly to gateways ${gatewayUrls}! Gateways response: `,
        uploadResult
    )

    const donHostedSecretsVersion = parseInt(uploadResult.version)
    console.log(`\n Secrets version: ${donHostedSecretsVersion}`)

}

uploadSecrets().catch((e) => {
    console.error(e)
    process.exit(1)
})


Expected Result in console
Secrets uploaded properly to gateways https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/! Gateways response


Hi DEEPAK, I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you check if you have sign the ToS with your address and have enough balance in it?

I faced a similar issue yesterday trying to use chainlink functions. Chainlink has a really good repo which I would recommend for you to check out. Check the functions-examples section of the repo.
Now coming to the above script, if you are using ethers.js version 6 or greater, I'd suggest you downgrade to 5.x.x because @chainlink/functions-toolkit package as of now is not properly compatible for ethers.js newer versions. To downgrade, use the following commands:
npm uninstall ethers
npm install ethers@5.7.2

Also, just to be on safer side, change the ethers import to

const ethers = require("ethers");

Now here is a similar script to yours which I am sharing. This script is inspired from many examples of the repo mentioned earlier and works fine assuming all versions of the packages are the same:
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const { SecretsManager } = require("@chainlink/functions-toolkit");
const ethers = require("ethers");
require("@chainlink/env-enc").config();

const routerAddress = "0xb83E47C2bC239B3bf370bc41e1459A34b41238D0";
const donId = "fun-ethereum-sepolia-1";
const gatewayUrls = [
  "https://01.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
  "https://02.functions-gateway.testnet.chain.link/",
];
const slotIdNumber = 0; // slot ID where to upload the secrets
const expirationTimeMinutes = 4000; // expiration time in minutes of the secrets

const uploadSecrets = async () => {
  // Initialize ethers signer and provider to interact with the contracts onchain
  const privateKey = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY; // fetch PRIVATE_KEY
  if (!privateKey)
    throw new Error(
      "Private key not provided - check your environment variables"
    );

  const rpcUrl = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL; // fetch Sepolia RPC URL
  if (!rpcUrl)
    throw new Error("RPC URL not provided - check your environment variables");

  const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);
  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey);
  const signer = wallet.connect(provider); // create ethers signer for signing transactions

  // Initialize SecretsManager
  const secretsManager = new SecretsManager({
    signer: signer,
    functionsRouterAddress: routerAddress,
    donId: donId,
  });
  await secretsManager.initialize();

  // Define secrets to be encrypted
  const secrets = { apiKey: process.env.OPENWEATHER_API_KEY };

  // Encrypt secrets
  console.log("Encrypting secrets...");
  const encryptedSecretsObj = await secretsManager.encryptSecrets(secrets);

  console.log("Secrets encrypted. Uploading to DON...");

  // Upload encrypted secrets to the DON
  const uploadResult = await secretsManager.uploadEncryptedSecretsToDON({
    encryptedSecretsHexstring: encryptedSecretsObj.encryptedSecrets,
    gatewayUrls: gatewayUrls,
    slotId: slotIdNumber,
    minutesUntilExpiration: expirationTimeMinutes,
  });

  if (!uploadResult.success) {
    throw new Error(
      `Encrypted secrets not uploaded. Response: ${JSON.stringify(
        uploadResult
      )}`
    );
  }

  console.log("✅ Secrets uploaded successfully!");

  // Fetch and log details of the uploaded secrets
  console.log(`Uploaded secrets details:`);
  console.log(`Version: ${uploadResult.version}`);
  console.log(`Success: ${uploadResult.success}`);
  console.log(`Response: ${JSON.stringify(uploadResult)}`);
  console.log(`To gateways: ${gatewayUrls}`);
};

uploadSecrets().catch((e) => {
  console.error(e);
  process.exit(1);
});

Replace the secrets and the private key with your own implementations for the same. Also I notice that you aren't importing require("dotenv").config() while using environment variables. Maybe that can be the issue too. If not, then try doing what I suggested above.
Also just in case you haven't stored your secrets locally in a .env.enc file, here are the steps to do so:
npm i @chainlink/env-enc

2.Set a password(you will have to do this everytime you kill current terminal and open new one):
npx env-enc set-pw


Once done setting up a password, add all environment variables' names and values(a variable added stays in .env.enc forever till you forcefully remove it. It's just that you need to set a password everytime you open a new terminal session to access it):

npx env-enc set


To access all variables:

npx env-enc view

Good. Now you can finally copy, paster and tinker the above script to your needs(try not to mess up the imports tho!). It should work. If you're still stuck feel free to reach out again.
